# Use asp to get the account id from xml?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am trying to make the asp page (not asp.net) to call out a specify data from the xml. This is for a user to check his balance on the site. The balance is located on a separate database. When a user login to the site, it will use his id to get the balance from the other database.

I worked out some code for calling out the info and balance but I am missing the part to use the id to get the correct data for the user. e.g. the user id is 12224, and the asp page will list his info and balance...

Can someone please give me a hand?

example url for where the database located: http:// testing .com/data/

example xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<account>
<info>
  <id>12224</id>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>DeBar</LastName>
  <dob>23051988</dob>
  <post>172</post>
 </info>
 <balance>
  <currentbalance>15</currentbalance>
  <balanceexpired>04062013</balanceexpired>
 </balance>

<info>
  <id>15276</id>
  <FirstName>Jerry</FirstName>
  <LastName>McC</LastName>
  <dob>21041989</dob>
  <post>387</post>
 </info>
 <balance>
  <currentbalance>0</currentbalance>
  <balanceexpired></balanceexpired>
 </balance>
</account>
```

login.asp - the latest code I worked out for calling the user's info:

```
<%
Set objXML2 = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objXML2.async = False
loadResult = objXML2.load(Server.MapPath("account2.xml"))
if not loadResult then
Response.write "no such record"
Response.end
end If
Set objNodes = objXML2.getElementsByTagName("account/info")
For i = 0 to objNodes.length - 1
Response.write Trim(objNodes(i).selectSingleNode("FirstName").Text)&"<br>"
Response.write Trim(objNodes(i).selectSingleNode("LastName").Text)&"<br>"
Response.write Trim(objNodes(i).selectSingleNode("post").Text)&"<br>"
Set objNodes2 = objXML2.getElementsByTagName("account/balance")
Response.write Trim(objNodes2(i).selectSingleNode("currentbalance").Text)&"<br><br>"
Next
set objNodes = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

'getting the current balance for the user.

%>
```

--edited--
I corrected the xml format and modified the code so the code is much cleaner. But the problem is it will show both record as I still cant figure how to tell it to call one of the record.

Comment: what happens when you try that code, what message do you see ?

Comment: no such record, thats because of I didnt specify what record to call out. Let say if I want to call out the record for <id>15276</id>, what code I need to add? thanks

Comment: check your code. you see "no records" when your `loadResult` is false, which could happen when your `objXML2.load(Server.MapPath("http:// testing .com/data/"))` fails. Server.MapPath('xx') is used to find the physical path of a file, you don't need that there.

Comment: thanks I just noticed that i didnt include the .xml in this sample code (indeed its on the actual code...) The problem is I dont know how to call out a specify record...